# How to write data to this dataflash memory

Tags: memory, flash, mbed

I'm trying to write data to a [W25P80 dataflash memory](http://datasheet.octopart.com/W25P80VSSIG-Winbond-datasheet-22205.pdf) using an mbed. The documentation says there is a read data instruction for reading data from a section of memory by sending the opcode 03h followed by the address to read. However, I see no corresponding write data instruction. So how is data written to the flash memory?

Answer (score 3):

send 06h to enable write then send page program (02h) which is the write function. (send 02h -> address 24 bits -> then min 2 bytes and up to 256bytes max) check 9.2.8 in the datasheet.

Comment: How would I read that data back?

Comment: Read Data - 9.2.6 opcode 03h and a 24 bit address  or fast read (0Bh- 24 bit address 1byte of dummy code) 9.2.7